# Python JSON dummy data generation from JSON schema

Tags: python, json, dummy-data

I am looking for a python library in which I can feed in my JSON schema and it generates dummy data. I have worked with a similar library in javascript dummy-json. Does anyone about a library which can do the same in python.

Comment: [Faker](http://fake-factory.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) combined with [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)?

Comment: Similar to this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dummy-json

Comment: Right, you could make something similar to that using Faker and the `json` module.

Comment: Should not this be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465588/convert-a-json-schema-to-a-python-class

Comment: I can't believe how this simple question was misinterpreted by so many.

Answer (score 5):

A library that does exactly this is [hypothesis-jsonschema](https://github.com/Zac-HD/hypothesis-jsonschema)

[Hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a library that can generate arbitrary data that conforms to a given specification.

[hypothesis-jsonschema](https://github.com/Zac-HD/hypothesis-jsonschema) makes it possible to convert JSON Schema into specifications that can be used by Hypothesis.

Here is an example showing a unit test written using Hypothesis and hypothesis-jsonschema:

```py
from hypothesis import given

from hypothesis_jsonschema import from_schema


@given(from_schema({"type": "integer", "minimum": 1, "exclusiveMaximum": 10}))
def test_integers(value):
    assert isinstance(value, int)
    assert 1 <= value < 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The most closest what I found within python is https://github.com/ueg1990/faker-schema, but it is not JSON-SCHEMA also there is nodejs implementation that is directly what you are searching for https://github.com/json-schema-faker/json-schema-faker

Answer (score -2):

here are the JSON schema generators proposed so far:

- https://github.com/gonvaled/jskemator (1 input but allows iteration)
- https://github.com/perenecabuto/json_schema_generator (1 input)
- https://github.com/rnd0101/json_schema_inferencer (1 input I think)
- https://github.com/wolverdude/GenSON/ (multiple inputs)
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/skinfer (multiple inputs)

bonus:

- http://www.jsonschema.net (1 input)

Comment: I dont want to generate schema. I have a schema or maybe one sample JSON. I want to generate random data from that. It should be random every time

Comment: @user1733735
online:
+ http://schematic-ipsum.herokuapp.com/
+ http://experiments.mennovanslooten.nl/2010/mockjson/tryit.html
+ http://www.json-generator.com/
+ http://json-generator.appspot.com/

python, perhabs this is help to you:
+ https://github.com/hamstah/apitools
+ http://www.joke2k.net/faker/